# query fail when has a where (reducers) in kerberos Cloudera quickstart

Tags: hive, kerberos, cloudera

When execute a query without condition the result is successfull
But when execute a query like `select * from tablexy where fielda = 'value'` the result is a follow error:

```
ERROR : Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.IOException(Failed on local 
exception: java.io.IOException: 

Couldn't setup connection for hive/quickstart.cloudera@CLOUDERA to 
    quickstart.cloudera/7.212.100.169:8032; Host Details : local host is: 
    "quickstart.cloudera":8032; )'
    "quickstart.cloudera/7.212.100.169"; destination host is: 
    java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: 
    Couldn't setup connection for hive/quickstart.cloudera@CLOUDERA to 
    quickstart.cloudera/7.212.100.169:8032; Host Details : local host is: 
    "quickstart.cloudera/7.212.100.169"; destination host is: 
    "quickstart.cloudera":8032;
```

Comment: *"When execute a query "* -- using **which tool**??? => Hue? a JDBC client? `hive` command-line utility (fat client)?

Comment: In hive cli, from console

Comment: IMHO, when you request a plain `SELECT` without a `WHERE` clause, the Hive CLI connects to HDFS directly using the "local mode" *(i.e. no YARN job)*; but the `WHERE` requires a real Map phase => Hive tries to connect to YARN ResourceManager on port 8032... and fails.

Comment: Now the next question is: do you really have a RM running and listening on port 8032? Did you try to run any other kind of YARN job *(Pig, Sqoop, Spark-on-YARN, whatever)*? Did you check the YARN CLI with something like `yarn application -list` or `yarn queue -status default`?

Comment: Side note: the conditions in a `WHERE` clause are applied in a Map task, not in a Reduce.